# how do i limit the number of tweets to one using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter

i am trying to display just the most recent tweet on my home page i see a working example however it is not limited to one how do i make this return just one tweet?

example: http://jsfiddle.net/pborreli/pJgyu/

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you are doing the right thing, I reckon the plugin you're using might be broken.

Comment: The script you're using for tweets doesn't take `tweets` param into consideration.

Comment: The documentation says fetch specifies the number of tweets that will be fetched and count the number of tweets that are returned out of the records fetched. Tried out in the fiddle, dint work out the way I expected sadly. :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you change your code to -

```
   $(function(){ 
    $('#tweets').tweet({
           count: 1,
           username: "jquery"
    });
   });
```

And your external reference in jsfiddle to -

http://tweet.seaofclouds.com/jquery.tweet.js

Then it should work.

http://jsfiddle.net/zSLWt/1/

Comment: is there a way of restricting the number of chars that come through for each tweet?

Comment: There seems to be no simple way, adding the line -
'template: function(x) {return x['tweet_raw_text'].substring(0,45)} 'under the username line will do the trick, but you may have to mess around with the code in the function body to get the effect you want.

Comment: im not sure how this is supposed to work sorry i need to add this under the username and then? im not sure?

Comment: The comment will mangle the formating but the code contained within the quotes below should return the first 45 characters of each tweet -'$(function(){ 
    $('#tweets').tweet({
           count: 1,
           username: "jquery",
     template: function(x) {return x['tweet_raw_text'].substring(0,45)}
    });
   });'

Answer (score 1):

You can use another [jquery twitter plugin](http://coda.co.za/content/projects/jquery.twitter/)

Steps:

Add a markup

```
<div id="twitter"> 
   results will be here
</div>
```

Call plugin method like

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $("#twitter").getTwitter({
                userName: "jquery",
                numTweets: 5,
                loaderText: "Loading tweets...",
                slideIn: true,
                slideDuration: 750,
                showHeading: true,
                headingText: "Latest Tweets",
                showProfileLink: true,
                showTimestamp: true
            });
        });
    </script>
```